# Rails looping a variable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have the following `developers_controller` and I want to perform a query based on the `location_params`.

In the `index_update` action I create a variable `location` with the `location_params` that the user gave as input for the research. I want to perform an `each` loop on this variable to filter the data from `@locations = Location.all` based on the user request.

This is my private method `location_params`:

```
def location_params
  params.require(:location).permit(:country, :location, :surfspot, :barbecue, :villa, :swimmingpool, :skiresort, :singleroom )
end
```

This is my `index_update` action:

```
def index_update
  location = Location.new(location_params)
  locations = Location.all
  location.each do |param, value|
    if value != nil
      locations = locations.where(param => value)
    end
  end
end
```

I can not find out how to loop the `location` variable.

---

This is my location model in my Rails console:

```
=> #<Location:0x000000036b6838
 id: nil,
 host_id: nil,
 description: nil,
 location: nil,
 singleroom: nil,
 sharedroom: nil,
 surfspot: nil,
 barbecue: nil,
 villa: nil,
 swimmingpool: nil,
 skiresort: nil,
 created_at: nil,
 updated_at: nil,
 country: nil,
 state: nil,
 houseimages: nil
```

Comment: What is your actual problem? The loop or the width of the div?

Comment: Instead of `if value != nil` use `if !value.nil?`.

Comment: Shouldn't you be looping over `locations`, not `location`?

Comment: i thought of using location fields to filter locations. The problem is that i do not know how to filter locations based on location fields, considering that the filter should not be applied if location = nil.

Comment: Where does `city` come from, it is not in the `location_params`? How does the raw params look like, how does `Location` look like and what is the expected output?

Comment: @theTinMan or `unless value.nil?`, or even better, `if value.present?`.

Comment: Sorry, I said `city`, but I never took the time to change `location.location` into `location.city` in my database. Yes, I will indeed use `value.present?` instead of `value != nil` thanks a lot! I posted the fields of my Location model

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do something like this to only use parameters with present values in the query:

```
def index_update
  query_attributes = location_params.select { |_, v| v.present? }
  locations = Location.where(query_attributes)
end
```

Or:

```
def index_update
  query_attributes = location_params.reject { |_, v| v.blank? }
  locations = Location.where(query_attributes)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can  `location_params` to instantiate a new location, then it's likely they're already  the proper format to pass into `where`:

```
def index_update
  locations = Location.where(location_params)
end
```

If you need to remove nil values from the params:

```
def index_update
  locations = Location.where(location_params.delete_if { |k,v| v.nil? })
end
```

Comment: The problem is that if some of the `location_params` are equal to `nil`, then the query will only select those entries with those fields empty. While I do not want to add that filter if the value is `nil`

Basically I want to return all results for the parameters given, this is why I was thinking of doing a loop and using the `if value.present?` condition

But indeed this answer is very good thanks!